# How to write a mongo query that returns fields with the expected results?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For instance I am trying to bring up the organization ids that are tagged to multiple countries in db.

```
 db.collection.find({"Region":{$in:["CHINA","JAPAN","SOUTH_KOREA"]}})
```

this doesnot give me the results that they have all 3 countries in the same document. Obviously $where does not work which I can query to bring up the fields that have more than 1 country in it.

Trying this for 2 days and need your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more background? What exactly are you trying to achieve? How do the documents of your collection look like and what is the desired output?

Comment: I want organizations to return that are tagged to all 3 countries above. What I am getting with this query is that orgs that are tagged to one country or two. Did not even see one org that includes all 3 countries. Hope it is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

> The $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements.

```
db.collection.find({"Region":{ $all :["CHINA","JAPAN","SOUTH_KOREA"] } })
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will go acording youre need's:

```
db.collection.find({
    $and: [
        { Region: {$in: /\bCHINA\b/i} },
        { Region: {$in: /\bJAPAN\b/i} },
        { Region: {$in: /\bSOUTH_KOREA\b/i} }
    ]
})
```

Comment: got this error ""errmsg" : "$in needs an array"," Dont know why

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are trying to match a document where the Region key is a list conataining all three countries.

```
  db.collection.find({$and: [
     {Region: {$in: ["CHINA"]}},
     {Region: {$in: ["JAPAN"]}},
     {Region: {$in: ["SOUTH_KOREA"]}}  
])
```

If so, this should work for you.

Comment: unfortunately does not work. I actually meant $in not working. $all does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

These two queries worked in my case. They are as simple as they look like but somehow I missed them our after many trials I may have miswritten them. Anyways here is the solution to my question:

```
db.collection.find({region:{$size:3}})
db.collection.find({ "region.2":{$exists:true}})
```